# pass the value from one viewmodel to another viewmodel in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

When I searched,I found,how to bind values from viewmodel to view but not viewmodel to viewmodel
I have a requirement to pass one property value from one viewmodel to another viewmodel as I need the initial property to be updated in first viewmodel then I want to use it in another viewmodel.because it is helpful while testing.

Assume that the below view model is the 1st view model,

```
var xx = xx || {};
    xx.yyy = xx.yyy || {};
    xx.yyy.zzz = function(object ) {
    var model = {};
    model.isTested= ko.observable(false);

   //below is the anonymous call to get the value(true/false):
    datasource.someFeatureEnable.isTested().done(function (featureToggle) {
    model.isTested(featureToggle.enabled);                
    });
}
```

I want to pass isTested(true/false) property value in another viewmodel because to run my application properly and make my tests pass

Answer (score 3):

You could make your second viewmodel have a dependency on your first viewmodel.

```
//this is the definition of your first view model.
function MainViewModel(dataSource) {
  var self = this;
  this.DataSource = dataSource;
  this.isTested = ko.observable(false);

  //a callable function that will run isTested check on someFeatureEnable
  this.TestSomeFeature = function() {
      self.DataSource.someFeatureEnable.isTested().done(function (featureToggle) {
          self.isTested(featureToggle.enabled);                
      });
  };
  return this;
}
//this is the definition of your second viewmodel
function SubViewModel(mainViewModel) {
  var self = this;
  self._mainViewModel = mainViewModel;
  //for read only access
  self.MainIsTested = function() { return self._mainViewModel.isTested(); }
  //for read/write
  self.MainIsTestedReference = self._mainViewModel.isTested
  return self;
}



//this is the code that initializes the whole page.
var main = new MainViewModel();
var sub = new SubViewModel(main);
//now run the check
main.TestSomeFeature();

//these are examples, showing how to get at the isTested property in your various viewmodels. The comments are what the code should return
sub.MainIsTested(); //false
main.isTested(); //false
//set isTested to true from the sub
sub.MainIsTestedReference(true);
//now main isTested returns true, because the sub viewmodel and the main viewmodel have references to the same object.
main.isTested(); // true
```

If you want to get more advanced and use an events based approach I'd recommend looking into ko.postbox, check out these references.

http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html

https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox

Comment: Hi scaryman :)...thanks for swift response.I am not completely clear with the above code.could please mention which lines of code to be part of 1st viewmodel and which lines of code will be part of 2nd view model?

Comment: I added some comments, hopefully the code is more clear to you. Judging by your StackOverflow score, you seem to be relatively inexperienced in javascript and knockout. I'd recommend you run through the tutorials at http://learn.knockoutjs.com/ and then, if you want to learn more about javascript, or understand the reasoning behind the code in the knockout tutorials, check out http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/. It's lengthy and dense, but very good stuff. Make sure to check out the reading list in the first section.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on whether the two viewmodels are in memory and available at the same time.  If so, then scaryman's suggestion of using knockout-postbox is a good one.  Or, you could use a client-side message bus such as postal.js (which is what I use).

If the viewmodels are not in memory and available at the same time, then introducing a third, static object (we'll call it "Z") would be necessary to handle something *similar to* an Event Aggregator pattern.  Essentially, viewmodel-1 would directly reference Z to store the `isTested` value there.  When viewmodel-2 instantiates, it would check with Z to get the `isTested` value.  This approach is not really an aggregation of events since you're not publishing messages on a channel (although, if you were to take the approach of sending messages with payload to Z, then it would be--way more complicated than it needs to be in this case).

If you're using AMD--say, require--you would simply require Z in each of your viewmodels (or, actually, in *every* viewmodel dependent upon Z).  You can read about require at http://www.requirejs.org.

Bare bones, we would have:

**viewmodel-1**

```
this.isTested = ko.observable(false);
var Z = require("Z");
Z.isTested(this.isTested());
```

**viewmodel-2**

```
this.isTested = false;  //Making the assumption that isTested doesn't have to be observable here--but it could be

var Z = require("Z");
this.isTested = Z.isTested();
```

Of course, you would elaborate on this so that Z could handle an array of viewmodels, perhaps with a dictionary object that could look up the viewmodel in question.

I would caution against scaryman's approach, though, of making viewmodels dependent on each other.  If you have many viewmodels that have an `isTested` relationship, the dependency graph could get pretty hairy.  I would concentrate `isTested` and perhaps other properties in one, third-party module: Z.

I would reiterate that Z should be static.  That means it should return an object literal, not a constructor function.

As a final note, I'm *not* suggesting the Mediator pattern, by the way.  I'm not suggesting that Z should store references to each of viewmodel-1 and viewmodel-2.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a event aggregator pattern, this is a decoupled and powerfull way for any listener to listen to any event without couppling to the publisher.

You can check how I did that for this library (SignalR library)

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/

I extracted the client side only code for your convenience

http://jsfiddle.net/ezkGt/

basicly what you do to pub / sub is

```
signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(Event, listener.onEvent, listener);

setInterval(function() {
    signalR.eventAggregator.publish(new Event(new Date()));
}, 500);

setTimeout(function() {
    signalR.eventAggregator.unsubscribe(listener);
}, 5000);
```